# How to get Iron-router query parameters in server hook

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to add a referral system to my project, so currently I am basing it off of [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/elie/referrals). The issue I am running into is my project only uses [accounts-google](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-google) and not accounts-password. The way this package works is it adds the iron router [query parameters](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/#query-parameters) for the referrerCode (`/register?r=ReferralCodeHere`)through a [preSignUpHook](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#options). I believe this only works with accounts-password wont work when creating an account with an API such as [accounts-google](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-google).

My idea around this is to use a `Meteor.users.before.insert` hook to grab the iron router query parameters and insert them into my `referrerCode` field in Meteor.users since I'm already using [Meteor Collection Hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) for a couple of other things.

The issue is I havent been able to find a way to get the query parameters on the server, I was hoping to do something like this:

```
Meteor.users.before.insert(function(userId, doc) {
  doc.referrerCode = Referrer._referrerCode; // Link 1 
});
```

([Link 1](https://github.com/elie222/meteor-referrals/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=_referrerQuery))

But this will just come up as undefined.

If I'm at my register page and it has a query like this for example: `example.com/register?r=12345` Then I run `Router.current().params.query.r` on the client it returns `12345`. Basically I just need to have that saved to the referralCode field in Meteor.users when a new user creates an account, if a referral code exists in the register URL.

I'm a bit lost with this one. I thought about setting it as a Session variable and then getting that in the before.insert hook, but that again only works on the client side. I'm thinking a meteor method might be best for this, but I'm not exactly sure how I would structure it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the referral token into `profile`
2. Use that in your hook

Below I've copied some code that I've used before. It is built around an `Invitations` collection that tracks who invited who:

client:

```
var profile = {};
... any other profile settings you've captured
if ( token ) profile.referralToken = token;
Accounts.createUser({ email: email, password: password, profile: profile }, function(err){ ...})
```

hook:

```
if ( options.profile.referralToken ){ // referral case
  var invitation = Invitations.findOne({ token: options.profile.referralToken });
  if ( invitation )
    user.invitationId = invitation._id; // the invitation used
    user.invitedBy = invitation.userId; // the referring user
  }
  delete options.profile.referralToken;
}
return user;
```